# Is Pikachu the only Pokémon to have its cry changed to its name?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I've just caught a Pikachu in Santalune Forest, and I couldn't help noticing that it **said its name**, instead of the electric buzzing of other games.. However every *other* Pokémon that I have run into so far still uses their standard 'cry'.

Has any other Pokémon been given a named cry? If so, what are they?

Comment: It also seems to have a different cry when it dies, it says "Pika pika...". Cute :3

Comment: If you choose to play with Pikachu in Pokémon Amie and pet him (Nintendogs style), you can get shocked by touching his/her red cheek. I've yet to see (and hear) such things from another Pokémon.

Comment: It seems in line with their major branding effort (this is their flagship character, after all), so I wouldn't be shocked at all if it was only Pikachu.  ...erm, pun unintended.

Comment: FYI: Raichu's cry is back to a typical electronic buzzing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only Pikachu.

All other Pokemon have kept their cries.

Answer (score 1):

Bidoof, too. Others got updates since their cries were a bit outdated.

Comment: Updated yes, but it still doesn't say its name. I noticed Charmander having a slightly higher toned growl as well