# Bugged Pokémon Go sounds

Tags: pokemon-go

I've been plaing Pokemon Go since yesterday. When I press the Pokemons in my inventory, extremeley few of them actually make a legit sound. Only Pikachu make the "legit" sound (him saying "Pikachu" obv.). The other Pokemons emit some kind of messed up, glitchy sound. Does anyone else have this problem, or know how to solve it?

Edit: Thing is that they all sound the same, a messed up "beep".

(I've tried to restart both the app and my iphone).

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/134197/is-pikachu-the-only-pok%C3%A9mon-to-have-its-cry-changed-to-its-name

Answer (score 4):

This is perfectly normal. Pokémon have always had various noises as their "cry" in the games, even in the originals.
In gen 6, all of the cries of older pokemon were "updated" to sound less harsh. Pikachu was the only pokemon changed to say its name instead of making an electric sound.

Answer (score 2):

They have their original sounds from the first game boy games (Red, Blue & Yellow edition). Maybe that's what you are hearing. Only Pikachu had its name as sound file in the Yellow edition since it was the main Pokémon character there and your starter Pokémon, like in the TV series. All the other ones sound kind of strange, if you don't know the old editions.

Answer (score 1):

What you're hearing is the game boy sound "cry" for the Pokemon. It's more of an electronic sound for all except pikachu.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure some of the other Pokemon have had better sounds in various games (eg Pokemon Stadium) but I'd have to look it up to be sure. What is interesting is that some of the animations don't match the sounds e.g. Jigglypuff seems to be animated as if we're saying its name but it's just an electric roar that comes out the speaker..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't witnessed the sound of the Pokemon because I keep my sound off/down, but in the Gameboy and DS games, most of the Pokemon had a glitchy sounding roar/sound. That might be where they're coming from.